# Converting JSON String (with Schema) to rows and columns - automatically

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse-analytics

I am on a project that has many columns in a PostgreSQL database with jsonb datatypes (from Wheel using the FHIR specification), containing complex JSON.  The example below is just one of many (possibly upwards of 100) columns that need to be converted to tables for the reporting team.  PowerBI can do most of this automatically without too much effort, but does not seem to be able to do all of it.
Here is the schema one of these json blobs:

```
root
 |-- intake_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- questionnaire: string (nullable = true)
 |-- questionnaire_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- identifier: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- use: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- item: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- answerOption: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- valueString: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- enableBehavior: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- enableWhen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- answerBoolean: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- answerInteger: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- answerString: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- operator: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- question: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- extension: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- valueCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- valueString: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- linkId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- repeats: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- required: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- publisher: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- resourceType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- useContext: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- valueCodeableConcept: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- coding: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- display: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
```

If have searched for many hours on Stack Overflow and have not found anything that meets my requirements (so please don't close as a duplicate)!
First off, I am mainly a SQL strong data engineer, and I am fumbling my way through using Python for doing this type of operation.  I've been mostly successful!  But on this one I am stumped.

The data is coming into the dataframe, via a JDBC call to the PostgreSQL server.  Then I've converted the jsonb column to a JSON string.  I've also managed to correctly gather the schema for this particular json blob.

I'd like for this schema (pasted above) to be able to automatically formatted to rows and columns for use in reporting.  Basically, the intakes questionnaire (represented by the schema above) should end up with 13 rows (13 questions).  I've managed to get 13 rows to show up, but have been left with manually having to use get_json_object() to do manual things.

Is there some way to do this automatically?  If PowerBI can do it, I'd think that Python (PySpark - Synapse) should be able to do something similar.
There is just way too many of these to have to fiddle with individually.

Help.  Please.

**I got the schema above by:**
--create schema for json column
questionnaire_schema = sqlContext.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.questionnaire)).schema
df2 = df.withColumn('questionnaire_json', from_json('questionnaire', questionnaire_schema))

**I've also managed to get the top level attributes exploded into columns:**
new_cols = df2.columns + df2.select('questionnaire_json.*').columns
df3 = df2.select('*', 'questionnaire_json.*').toDF(*new_cols).drop('questionnaire_json')

But even after that, I've still got to go deeper and make the array elements into rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`explode` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) to produce multiple rows, one per question. Here you have an small example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", [1,2]), ("b", [3,4,5])], ["c1", "c2"])
>>> df.withColumn("c3", F.explode(df.c2)).show()
+---+---------+---+
| c1|       c2| c3|
+---+---------+---+
|  a|   [1, 2]|  1|
|  a|   [1, 2]|  2|
|  b|[3, 4, 5]|  3|
|  b|[3, 4, 5]|  4|
|  b|[3, 4, 5]|  5|
+---+---------+---+
```